# how do i make a car in Ursina firstpersoncontroller rotate using the 'a' and 'd' keys, not the mouse

Tags: python, ursina

in Ursina i am trying to make a simple 3d car game with FirstPersonController, how do i make the player/car rotate using 'a' and 'd' keys, without using the mouse. turn like a car would when you turn a corner in real life the view moves with the turn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: **disable** mouse for `FirstPersonController` and in `update` function check for key inputs and increase or decrease `rotation_y` according to the keys.

Answer (score 1):

After line

```
def update():
```

Try to add following lines:

```
    if held_keys['d']:                          # If d is pressed
        car.rotation_y += time.dt * 5                # turn car right
        camera.rotation_y += time.dt * 5             # turn camera right
    if held_keys['a']:                          # If a is pressed
        camera.rotation_y -= time.dt * 5             # turn camera left
        car.rotation_y -= time.dt * 5                # turn car left
```